# Factoring a polynomial with integer coefficients

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathematics

I haven't programmed in a while and need to improve my code in any way possible: efficiency, readability, etc. This program is for getting integer coefficients of any polynomial and factoring: ex.

$$ 2x^2+8x^1+8 \longrightarrow 2(x+2)(x+2) $$

What advice can you offer to help me out?

### factor.py (Main file)

```
#!/usr/local/bin python
#factor.py

import interface
from math import log10
from fractions import Fraction

# greatest common divisor
def gcd(poly):
    # shift unused place values
    x = ""
    ex = 0
    for i in range(len(poly)-1,-1,-1):
        if(poly[i] == 0):
            if(x == ""):
                x = "x"
            elif(x == "x"):
                x = "x^"
            ex += 1
            poly.pop()
    if(ex > 1):
        x += str(ex)

    # Euclidian Algorithm
    divisor, temp = poly[0], poly[1]
    # get divisor for first 2 elements
    while(temp):
        divisor, temp = temp, divisor % temp
    # get divisor for rest of elements
    if(len(poly) > 2):
        for i in poly[2:]:
            temp = i
            while(temp):
                divisor, temp = temp, divisor % temp
    # if first term is negative -> divisor must be negative
    if(poly[0] < 0 and not (divisor < 0)):
        divisor *= -1

    if(divisor == 1):
        divisor = ""
    else:
        # factor out common divider
        for i in range(len(poly)):
            poly[i] = int(poly[i] / divisor)

    return str(divisor) + x

# rational zero test to extract zeros
def rzt(poly):
    # factors of constant
    p = []
    # factors of coefficient
    q = []
    # positive storage
    temppos = []
    # negative storage
    tempneg = []
    # make list of all possibile factors (negative inclusive)
    for i in range(1,poly[-1]+1):
        if(poly[-1] % i == 0):
            temppos.append(i)
            tempneg.insert(0,-i)
    p = tempneg + temppos

    # reset storage
    temppos = []
    tempneg = []
    # make list of all possibile factors (negative inclusive)
    for i in range(1,poly[0]+1):
        if(poly[0] % i == 0):
            temppos.append(i)
            tempneg.insert(0,-i)
    q = tempneg + temppos

    # find all possibile zeros
    zeros = []
    for i in p:
        for j in q:
            zero = Fraction(i,j)
            if(zero not in zeros):
                # sum of all terms
                sum = 0
                for k in range(len(poly)):
                    sum += poly[k] * int(zero) ** (len(poly) - 1 - k)
                # check if poly(zero) == 0
                if(sum == 0):
                    zeros.append(zero)
    return zeros

# synthetic divison to check zeros
def synthdiv():
    global remainder
    remainder = poly
    divisors = []
    temp = []
    while(True):
        factors = rzt(remainder)
        if(factors == []):
            #return factors
            break
        for i in range(len(factors)):
            for j in range(len(remainder)):
                if(j == 0):
                    temp.append(remainder[j])
                else:
                    temp.append(remainder[j] + temp[j - 1] * int(factors[i]))
            if(temp[-1] == 0):
                temp.pop()
            else:
                print("Error synthdiv")
                return
            divisors.append(int(factors[i]))
            remainder = temp
            temp = []
    return divisors



# gets polynomial from user
poly = interface.getpoly()

# common divisor
cdivisor = gcd(poly)



remainder = []
divisors = synthdiv()

#if(divisors == []):
#    print("Cannot be factored into rational numbers")
#    print()
#else:

if(cdivisor != ""):
    print(str(cdivisor),end='')
for i in range(len(divisors)):
    print("(x", end='')
    if(divisors[i] >= 0):
        print(" - ", end='')
    else:
        print(" + ", end='')
    print(str(divisors[i])[1:] + ")", end='')
if(remainder != [1]):
    print("(", end='')
    interface.printpoly(remainder)
    print(")", end='')
print("\n")

#while(True):
#    zeros = rzt(temppoly)
#    print(zeros)
#    if(len(zeros) == 0):
#        break
#    for i in zeros:
#        temppoly = polydiv([1,-int(i)],temppoly)
#        factors.append([1,-int(i)])
```

### interface.py (Controls input and output to console)

```
#!/usr/local/bin python
#interface.py

import sys

def error():
    print("Invalid entry: Please enter an integer greater than 1")
def usage():
    print("usage: python3 factor.py [a] [b] ...")
    print()
    sys.exit()

# gets polynomial from user
def getpoly():
    # reset polynomial if assigned before
    polynomial = []

    if(len(sys.argv) > 2):
        for i in sys.argv[1:]:
            try:
                int(i)
            except ValueError:
                usage()
        polynomial = list(map(int, sys.argv[1:]))

    elif(len(sys.argv) == 1):
        # gets number of terms of [int]polynomial
        terms = 0
        while(True):
            try:
                terms = int(input("# of terms: "))
                #checks for value 0
                if(terms <= 1):
                    error()
                    continue
                break
            except ValueError:
                error()
        terms = int(terms)
        # collects [int] for each index of polynomial
        for i in range(terms):
            val = 0
            while(True):
                try:
                    val = int(input("Enter value of term " + str(i+1) + ": "))
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    error()
            polynomial.append(val)

    else:
        usage()


    # check that user submission is correct.
    while(True):
        # show user input
        print("The polynomial you entered is:\t", end='')
        printpoly(polynomial)
        print()
        proceed = input("Would you like to proceed? y/n: ")
        if(proceed == "y" or proceed == "Y"):
            return polynomial
            break
        elif(proceed == "n" or proceed == "N"):
            sys.argv = []
            return getpoly()
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter y or n")


# prints [readable]polynomial for user
def printpoly(poly):
    for i in range(len(poly)):
        if(i == len(poly)-1):
            print(str(poly[i]), end='')
        elif(i < len(poly) - 1):
            coefficient = str(poly[i])
            if(poly[i] == 1):
                coefficient = ""

            if(i == len(poly)-2):
                print(coefficient + "x", end='')
            else:
                print(coefficient + "x^" + str(len(poly) - 1 - i), end='')
            print(" + ", end='')
```

Comment: Re: conventions, please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions), especially the part about titles, and [edit] your post accordingly. Welcome to Code Review :)